# ggpairs factor not labeling as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpairs

I have the following data, and I transform "method" to a factor then do a ggpairs plot. However, as you can see, the ggpairs plot does not label the two factor levels in the output as I expected. based on other examples, it should label "MBI" and "traditional" above the box-plots.

```
structure(list(ID = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 39L, 40L, 44L, 46L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 60L), OptPost = c(50L, 67L, 61L, 92L, 59L, 16L, 42L, 69L, 
42L, 59L, 44L, 52L, 84L, 91L, 84L, 59L, 84L, 84L, 59L, 67L, 67L, 
67L, 70L, 50L, 84L, 50L, 20L, 46L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 50L, 55L, 75L, 
50L, 39L, 55L), method = c("MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", 
"MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", 
"MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "MBI", "traditional", 
"traditional", "traditional", "traditional", "traditional", "traditional", 
"traditional", "traditional", "traditional", "traditional", "traditional", 
"traditional", "traditional", "traditional", "traditional", "traditional"
), gender = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), OptPre = c(50L, 50L, 30L, 
67L, 42L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 42L, 50L, 0L, 25L, 50L, 83L, 17L, 17L, 
24L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 28L, 55L, 58L, 42L, 71L, 41L, 15L, 42L, 17L, 
44L, 16L, 32L, 50L, 42L, 32L, 30L, 42L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-37L))

optics_df <- optics_df %>% mutate(method = as.factor(method))

ggpairs(optics_df[, -1],
        mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = method),)

ggpairs(optics_df[, -1], aes(color = method)) #same as above
```

[image: ggpairs plot]

I attempted to ggpairs plot for a dataset, expected factor to be labeled automatically yet it is not.

Note: while a legend is acceptable as a solution, we really want it to be included in the labels as with this example for gender:
[ggpairs plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGmcd.png)

edit:
the answers provided so far are good and very helpful! but they don't fix the issue of labeling the actual column, they only add a legend.

I did some additional experimenting and I was able to notice that when we move the 'method' column to the end of the dataframe, the labels are generated automatically. can someone with a better understanding of ggpairs explain why this is the case?
[image: ggpairs fixed]

Comment: `+ theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  labs(color = "method")`

Comment: weird ... you see the group labels with `ggpairs(optics_df[,1:3], aes(color = method))` but not `ggpairs(optics_df[,1:4], aes(color = method))` . You can also see with `ggpairs(optics_df[,c(1,2,4,3)], aes(color = method))` e.g. it seems there is a need to move the variable to the last column.  I don't know if this is expected / documented behaviour or a bug (that siad the examples in the docs don't support that theory!!)

Comment: @user20650 i noticed the same in a comment that was auto-deleted and is now included as an edit! do you think this is a bug i should report? i also find nothing in the documentation about this behavior

Comment: another question: now the labels are appearing on the x axis, but can we also get them to appear on the y axis?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to have the legend of the boxplot, you could use the `legend` argument:

> a numeric vector of length 2 provides the location of the plot to use
> the legend for the plot matrix's legend. Such as legend = c(3,5) which
> will use the legend from the plot in the third row and fifth column

So the first row and second column should be your input. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(GGally)
ggpairs(optics_df[, -1],
        mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = method),
        legend = c(1,2))
```

[image]

To have it more generalized you could use the legend of the barplot which shows the colors of the factor like this:

```r
library(GGally)
ggpairs(optics_df[, -1],
        mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = method),
        legend = c(2,2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>